# How to reload Google Apps Script webapp upon button click?

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I have a Google Apps Script webapp deployed onto a Google Pages site. It shows a button that creates a new spreadsheet when clicked. I also want it to reload the webapp (so not the full page, just the webapp) if the spreadsheet creation was successful (and display some error message if it wasn't). I have a vague idea it has to be done with a successHandler but I'm not sure how to proceed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I'd suggest:

Create one html page with two divs called page (page1, page2). set Page2 to not show originally:

```
<div id="page1" style="display:block">
<input type="button" id="load" name="button" value="CHOOSE" onclick="inputProject(this.parentNode)"  /></div>
<div id="page2" style="display: none">sheet created!</div>
```

and then the script section looks something like this

```
<script>
function inputProject(project){
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(result){
console.log(result);
document.getElementById('page2').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('page1').style.display = "none";
})
}.MAKESPREADSHEET();//YOUR GOOGLE-SIDE SCRIPT
</script>
```

this hides your first page when the script is finished running and shows the second one. Giving you that "reload" type idea you had in mind.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I think I get the overall logic but I'm struggling with the script a bit. Could you please explain it's flow in a bit more detail?

I've also implemented it and I think the server side function does not run when I click the 'CHOOSE' button. Also, the webapp doesn't change.

Comment: Do you get any ```result``` in your ```console.log```? Also, by ```server side``` you mean the function on the ```script``` tag or the one on the ```.gs``` file?

Comment: result in this case will be whatever is returned from the .gs function. and yes by server side I meant the gs file functions.